# How to retrieve parent entities with a collection of child entities using hibernate jpa native query?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I normally use JPQL to query database, but today I have to use native query for performance reason and for features not available in JPQL (join subquery). Using JPQL one can use join fetch to retrieve parent entities along with their collections of child entities. However when I try to use native query, for each parent entity, multiple rows are returned, each row contains the data of the parent and one of its children. The returned List then contains duplicated objects for the parent. Suppose one parent have two children, then the following query returns 2 parents in the list instead of 1.

```
@Query(value="select * from Parent p left join Child c on p.parent_id = c.parent_id", nativeQuery = true)
List<Parent> getParents()
```

Anyone knows how to avoid the duplicated parents so it returns same result as below

```
@Query(value="select p from Parent p left join fetch p.children")
List<Parent> getParents()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't share the native query, it's hard to tell what causes the cardinality increase, but using `DISTINCT` might be a way to go, but that depends on what you actually select.

If you are interested in an approach that allows you to stay in the realm of the JPA model, you should take a look at [Blaze-Persistence](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#core-quick-start) which offers subquery support in the from clause on top of JPA/Hibernate: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/core/manual/en_US/index.html#subquery-in-from-clause

With [Entity-Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage) and the [Spring-Data integration](https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features) all this can be very simple. If you share your use case and are interested, I can help you figure out how this could look like.